# Can't access google calendar API with multiple domains

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-developers-console

1. I needed to fetch google calendar of various clients for my app
2. I created a project in google cloud, activated calendar api scopes in oAUTH2.0 credentials
3. In authorised domains, I put my org email ID.
4. I published the app
5. Now i am able to fetch calendar of all people having domain of getvymo.com but not of gmail.com or any other domain
6. I tried putting gmail.com in authorised domain but it is not allowing me even to access calendar APIs via gmail domain
7. Now i have 50+ clients with 50+ domains, do i need to manually put every client's domain in authorised domain, is n't there a way to auto accept any domain ?

Comment: Are you using a service account or something to do this?   Authorized domains is normally used to configure domain wide delegation with a service account.   You cant do that with a standard gmail address.   Drop the authorized domains and just use standard Oauth2 to request consent of the user to access their data.

Comment: I was using OAUTH 2.0 keys, found solution, posting in answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with your Google Cloud project not working with any domains other than the one you used to create it, you can try removing all of the authorized domains from your project. This will force your project to use the default domain, which is the one you used to create it.

Note: Removing all of the authorized domains from your project may require you to resubmit your app for verification from Google.

Steps -

1. Go to your project in `https://console.cloud.google.com/`
2. Go to O-AUTH consent screen, below you can edit in Authorised domains.